# Cell colors in multiDatesPicker jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have implemented a jquery multiDatesPicker and this is what it looks like:
[image]

I want to color some of these dates/cells red, some blue and some green. More generally, I want to know:

1. What does a for loop for a multiDatesPicker look like?
2. Assuming I can access each date/cell in the multiDatesPicker using the for loop, how do I change the cell's background color(**not** the text color)?

For context, this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker({
        minDate : minDateString,
        maxDate: maxDateString,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { inst.settings.defaultDate = dateText; }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Shreeman

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].